# how to apply cascade delete

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Problem with my delete Tsql when it come to delete the associate record can someone help me how to fix it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_Resource]
@ResID INT,

@UserID uniqueidentifier  

AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Topics_Resources]
      WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Topics_Resources].ResourceID =  @ResID



    DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Likes]
      WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Likes].resourceID = @ResID

     declare @BookmarkID  INT;
     SET  @BookmarkID  =  (SELECT [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks].id  FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks] WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks].resourceID = @ResID and Bookmarks.userID = @UserID)
     DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks]
      WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks].resourceID = @ResID

      DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].Bookmarks_Groups 
      WHERE Bookmarks_Groups.bookmarkID = @BookmarkID

     delete FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship]
      WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship].fk_parent = @ResID


    DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Skills_Resources]
      WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Skills_Resources].ResourceID = @ResID




     DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources]
      WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources].Id  = @ResID 

END
```

the error

A critical error has occurred. The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Resources_Relationship_Resources1". The conflict occurred in database "ideaPark_DB", table "dbo.Resources_Relationship", column 'fk_child'. The statement has been terminated. -

Comment: Where does "cascade delete" come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following before your final delete from `Resources`

```
delete FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship]
WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship].fk_chid = @ResID
```

Your `Resources_Relationship` table has two FK's back to the `Resources` table, you were only handling one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

The first:

```
DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks]
WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Bookmarks].resourceID = @ResID

DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].Bookmarks_Groups 
WHERE Bookmarks_Groups.bookmarkID = @BookmarkID
```

I'd change the order of these delete because bookmark_groups is middle table between bookmarks and groups.

The second:

After this delete:

```
DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship]
WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship].fk_parent = @ResID
```

You must add this:

```
DELETE FROM [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship]
WHERE [ideaPark_DB].[dbo].[Resources_Relationship].fk_child = @ResID
```